# how to use the return type of "fgetc" blow the code?

Tags: c, fgetc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   while(1)
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) )
      {
          break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
}
```

here in the code,the fgetc(fp) use the int as this return type,so why we use "printf("%c",c);" rather than "print("%d",c);"

Comment: If you want to see the integer representation of `c` you may use `%d`.

Comment: Does https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html explain things adequately? The % codes don't stand for exact data types; they stand for *ways of interpreting the information* (that happen to have some rough expectations on what data is provided).

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you should definitely check the return from `fopen()` before proceeding to that `while(1)`.

Comment: Somewhat related: the reason that `fgetc` returns `int` instead of `char` as you might expect, is that the return value has to be able to represent every possible `char` value as well as the special value `EOF` to indicate failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `printf` format string, `%c` means “convert the `int` argument to an `unsigned char` and print the character it is the code for.”

`%d` means “convert the `int` argument to a decimal numeral and print that numeral.”

Comment: this answer is absolutely what I want

Comment: Also worth noting: for a variadic function, all integral types smaller than `int` get promoted to it. Likewise for `double`.

Comment: @bruceherring If this answers your question, consider pressing the checkmark on the left to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok,I am little late

Answer (score 1):

`%c` will print it as a `character`

`%d` will print it as a decimal representation.

Example:

```
void printAsChar(const char *x)
{
    while(*x)
    {
        printf("%c\n", *x++);
    }
}

void printAsDecimal(const char *x)
{
    while(*x)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *x++);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    printAsChar("hello");
    printf("------------\n");
    printAsDecimal("hello");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rx8oqaMnT

result:

```
h
e
l
l
o
------------
104
101
108
108
111
```

`104` is an ASCII code of `'h'`, `101` code of `'e'` etc